# css background repeat space has an issue

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100");
  background-size: 100px;
  background-repeat: space;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

it should fill the whole page with that picture but it only fits one row.

i changed the size to set or intial it dosent matter.and the round reapeat dosnet work too.it fils the row but it comprses like a hundred images in a col

Comment: You don't seem to have given body any height.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any content taking up the space. Your html tag practically has no height and the images that are showing in 1 row are overflowing. Increase the html height to 100% and the images will cover the entire viewport:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100");
  background-size: 100px;
  background-repeat: space;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Edit: Updated the html style to be `min-height:100%` as per @Temani's recommendation.

Comment: min-height will be more suitable in case we a lot of content

Answer (score -1):

If i understood your questions right , i think you want the background to fill the available space

```
 body{
            background-image: url("any image);
             background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
```

the background-repeat:no-repeat will only show it once and the cover to fill all space available . Is this what you wanted to do ?